# Exception in template helper: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have been struggling with getting a userprofile to display for a specific user for some time now and I have been reasonably successful. I have ht oe problem where I get the error in the heading.

I publish a schools collection like this

```
Meteor.publish("schoolData", function () {
  return Schools.find();
});
```

My subscription looks like this

```
Meteor.subscribe('schoolData');
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<template name="userProfile">
    <title>My Profile</title>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name: </td>
            <td>{{userName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Registered E-mail: </td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact E-mail: </td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number: </td>
            <td>{{phoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>School: </td>
            <td>{{schoolName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First year: </td>
            <td>{{firstSchoolYear}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last year: </td>
            <td>{{lastSchoolYear}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Matriculated? </td>
            <td>{{matriculated}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>House Name: </td>
            <td>{{houseName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country living in: </td>
            <td>{{country}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City living in: </td>
            <td>{{cityOfResidence}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Industry employed in: </td>
            <td>{{emplIndustry}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

and the javascript looks like this

```
Template.userProfile.helpers({
    email: function() {return Meteor.user().emails[0].address},
    userName: function () {return Meteor.user().username},
    firstName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.firstname},
    lastName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.lastname},
    phoneNumber: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.phone},
    schoolName: function () {return     Schools.findOne(Meteor.user().profile.schoolName).name;},
    firstSchoolYear: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.firstschoolyear},
    lastSchoolYear: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.lastschoolyear},
    matriculated: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.matriculated},
    houseName: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.housename},
    country: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.country},
    cityOfResidence: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.cityofresidence},
    emplIndustry: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.emplindustry},
    signedUp: function () {return Meteor.user().profile.createdAt},
});
```

I seem to get the Error
    Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
and it mees this is from the Schools collection. 
Can someone help me spot my mistake please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is better way to do what you want to achieve- wrap all your html with {{#with user}} tags like this:

```
<template name="userProfile">
  {{#with user}}
    <title>My Profile</title>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name: </td>
            <td>{{userName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Registered E-mail: </td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact E-mail: </td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number: </td>
            <td>{{phoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>School: </td>
            <td>{{schoolName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First year: </td>
            <td>{{firstSchoolYear}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last year: </td>
            <td>{{lastSchoolYear}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Matriculated? </td>
            <td>{{matriculated}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>House Name: </td>
            <td>{{houseName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country living in: </td>
            <td>{{country}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City living in: </td>
            <td>{{cityOfResidence}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Industry employed in: </td>
            <td>{{emplIndustry}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{{/with}}
</template>
```

And helper like:

```
user: function(){return Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()});
```

Now you can use all data from your user collection in html without helpers

And to your question - you made your query wrong, it should look like this:

```
schoolName: function () {
    return Schools.findOne({name:Meteor.user().profile.schoolName}).name;
},
```

I assumed you want to check school by `name`, if you have `_id` of it in `profile.schoolName` change `name` with `_id`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer,
I have made changes to the code as you suggested but I still get undefined as an error.
I ran the query from the console of the browser and got this response

    Schools.findOne({name:Meteor.user().profile.schoolName.name});
    undefined

Do you think it could be a permissions problem?

Comment: I tried this query as well. Withouth the .name and it returns the whole object.
Schools.findOne({_id:Meteor.user().profile.schoolName});
Object {_id: "HGNzCYGszPGcG2Aab", name: "High School For Boys"}

Comment: Then this second should work with .name at the end. If you kept in profile.schoolName "HGNzCYGszPGcG2Aab" then you should compare it to id, if you had "High School For Boys" then you should compare it to name in query

Comment: I have changed the code to use _id as you suggested but unfortunately adding the .name to the end results in the undefined error. THanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I was being a plank. This was working I just had the .name in the incorrect place. Thank you very much.